# Create a form from template depending on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Hi I want to know if its possible to use javascript/jquery or Ajax to show a form based on a radio button.

For example I have 2 different forms And if the one radio button is checked I want to load the first form but if the second radio button is checked I want to load the second form. Is this possible using Ajax?

If its easier I just need to show/remove a select box and a input box depending on the radio button.

Thanks

Comment: You could load both from start to avoid a load for the user... And hide the one you don't want. I often do it.

Comment: Yes I thought of that but what if I want to check wether they are filled in? :) wouldn't it refuse the form if its not filled but submitted and you have this autofill tools this days.. could give a lot of trouble..

Comment: Hide and disable all fields from the form you don't want.
You can use $(YourForm).find(":input").prop("disabled", true) (may be improved)

Answer (score 1):

Put both forms on the page and hide then both.  Then, put a change event handler for the radio button list that has your "Form 1" and "Form 2" selections.  Toggle the display of your forms accordingly.

Then, include within your forms separate submission buttons.  Write click event handlers for them that validate the required fields for either form.

Answer (score 0):

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/ft0se9Ld/

HTML :

```
Choose your form<br/>
<input type="radio" name="rdForm" value="form1" checked="checked">form1
<input type="radio" name="rdForm" value="form2">form2


<div id="form1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br/>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</div>
<br/>

<div id="form2" style="display:none;">
    adress: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br/>
    stuff: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(':radio[name="rdForm"]').change(function() {
    var choosenForm = $(this).filter(':checked').val();

    if(choosenForm === "form1"){
        $("#form1").show();
        $("#form2").hide();
    }else if(choosenForm === "form2"){
        $("#form1").hide();
        $("#form2").show();
    }
});
```